# Three.js showing white model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am trying to display a 3D .obj model in a webpage using three.js. The model is an obj file. I can see the model using the three.js script but it has a weird while color.

The original model looks like [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQR3L.png). (Used a 3D viewer to upload the obj file). But the output I am getting is totally white. [three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS2cD.png)

```
  <script>
      if (!Detector.webgl) {
          Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
      }

      var container;

      var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
      var lighting, ambient, keyLight, fillLight, backLight;

      init();
      animate();

      function init() {
          container = document.createElement('div');
          document.body.appendChild(container);

          /* Camera */
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /window.innerHeight, 1, 90000000000);
          camera.position.z = 4000;

          /* Scene */
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          lighting = false;

          ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
          scene.add(ambient);

          keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 10%, 7%)'), 1.0);
          keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

          fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new                THREE.Color('hsl(240, 10%, 7%)'), 0.75);

          fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

          backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
          backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

          /* Model */
          var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
          mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('caster/');
          mtlLoader.setPath('caster/');
          mtlLoader.load('edger-QLgame.mtl', function (materials) {

          materials.preload();

          //materials.materials.default.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
          //materials.materials.default.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

          var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
          //objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
          mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('caster/');
          objLoader.setPath('caster/');
          objLoader.load('edger-QLgame.obj', function (object) {
              scene.add(object);
          });
      });

      /* Renderer */
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 0%, 10%)"));
      renderer.gammaOutput = true;

      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      /* Controls */
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true;
      controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
      controls.enableZoom = true;

     /* Events */
     window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
     window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyboardEvent, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);   
}

function onKeyboardEvent(e) {  
    if (e.code === 'KeyL') {
        lighting = !lighting;

        if (lighting) {
            ambient.intensity = 0.25;
            scene.add(keyLight);
            scene.add(fillLight);
            scene.add(backLight);
        } else {
            ambient.intensity = 1.0;
            scene.remove(keyLight);
            scene.remove(fillLight);
            scene.remove(backLight);
        }
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
}
document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
    var fovMAX = 160;
    var fovMIN = 1;

    camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
    camera.fov = Math.max( Math.min( camera.fov, fovMAX ), fovMIN );
    camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makePerspective(camera.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, camera.near, camera.far);
}
```

Comment: you must assign a materials from mtl file to object. but you have comented this part (...setMaterials...)

Comment: I have commented that part for testing purpose. The results are similar even if I add the mtl file.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to dim or turn off the AmbientLight. In combination with white materials set in the mtl file or white default materials if mtl is not set, it will produced just white without shades. The other lights won't have any effect.

Comment: If I turn off the ambient light the model becomes too dark.

Comment: But do you see any shades? Maybe set AmbientLight to `0x888888`.

Comment: Nope, the shades are not visible.